# Single Board Computer/Microcontroller Recommendations for controlling large DC motors?

Tags: motor, microcontroller

Hey looking for recommendations. Right now I am using a sabertooth 2x25 motor controller for my drive train, receiving signals from a raspberry pi. From what I am seeing online - there is a lot of mixed reviews regarding this sort of setup. Everything seems to be running fine on my end, but I am curious to see what is the best optimal way to interface and program a large DC motor. Reasons why I decided to use a pi was because I needed ROS to be set up with my robot to perform autonomous tasks.

I understand that the pi's clock is not powerful enough to give precise PWM output signals, while its running computations at the same time. Is there a board out there that could possibly handle both?

Edit: Around 6A continuous load for the motors, 12 V

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what 'large DC Motor' means? Optionally if your motor amperage is <2 amps, you could use a L298 with inputs from Raspi.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, added my specs to the main desc. I'm using 2 6A, 12V motors

Comment: You could use existing MOSFET based custom built drivers like [these](http://robokits.co.in/motor-drives/dc-motor-driver-20a) and you could make one using the circuit [here](http://www.eleccircuit.com/24vdc-motor-speed-control-with-20a-shot-circuit-protection/)
The Idea is to basically isolate your Raspi board with the Higher Current by using the Raspi as the base signal.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* BAMercury, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: In general it is better ask *How do I solve this problem?* than *What do I need to buy to solve my problem in this way?* as you may preclude answers providing better solutions. If you edit your question to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see, then we can re-open this question for you.